# Sequence of real numbers which are distinct modulo 1.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a sequence of real numbers which are distinct modulo 1. Are the sequences
$$\{\varepsilon x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N} \ \ (\varepsilon\rightarrow 0), \ \ \ \left\{\frac{\varepsilon x_n}{\sin(x_n-x_m)}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb N} \ \ (\varepsilon\rightarrow 0), m\neq n$$
still composed by real numbers which are distinct modulo 1?

Comment: What does $\epsilon\to0$ mean in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any sequence of distinct reals, there are at most countably many $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon x_n\equiv x_m\pmod 1$ for some $n,m$. This is because these epsilon are characterized by three integers $n,m,\epsilon(x_n-x_m)$. Hence for all sufficiently small positive $\epsilon$, the sequence $\{\epsilon x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ will be composed of real numbers distinct modulo $1$.

The sequence with $\sin(x_n-x_m)$ in the denominator may not even be a sequence of real numbers because $x_n-x_m$ may be a multiple of $\pi$. Nevertheless, if we ignore theses exceptions the argument of the above still applies.

Comment: Thanks. But, are $x$ and $y$ said to be distinct real numbers modulo $1$ if $x-y$ is not an integer?